# SPARQL Wikidata Query to retrieve url for multiple languages

Tags: sparql, wikipedia, wikidata, graphdb, blazegraph

I wrote this Sparql query to retrieve item labels in multiple language

```
  SELECT ?item ?en ?es ?it  WHERE {
  { ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q6256. }
  UNION
  { ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q1250464. }
  UNION
  { ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q3624078. }
  UNION
  { ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q619610. }
  UNION
  { ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q179164. }
  UNION
  { ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q7270. }
  ?item rdfs:label ?en filter (lang(?en) = "en").
  ?item rdfs:label ?es filter (lang(?es) = "es").
  ?item rdfs:label ?it filter (lang(?it) = "it").

} LIMIT 2
```

that gives

```
{
  "item": {
    "type": "uri",
    "value": "http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q43"
  },
  "en": {
    "xml:lang": "en",
    "type": "literal",
    "value": "Turkey"
  },
  "es": {
    "xml:lang": "es",
    "type": "literal",
    "value": "Turquía"
  },
  "it": {
    "xml:lang": "it",
    "type": "literal",
    "value": "Turchia"
  }
}
```

I would like now to retrieve item url for each language. An approach could be the following

```
SELECT ?cid ?country ?article_en  ?article_de WHERE {
    ?cid wdt:P31 wd:Q3624078 .
    OPTIONAL {
        ?cid rdfs:label ?country filter (lang(?country) = "en") .
    }
  OPTIONAL {
        ?cid rdfs:label ?country filter (lang(?country) = "de") .
    }
    OPTIONAL {
      ?article_en schema:about ?cid .
      ?article_en schema:inLanguage "en" .
      FILTER (SUBSTR(str(?article_en), 1, 25) = "https://en.wikipedia.org/")
    }
  OPTIONAL {
      ?article_de schema:about ?cid .
      ?article_de schema:inLanguage "de" .
      FILTER (SUBSTR(str(?article_de), 1, 25) = "https://de.wikipedia.org/")
    }
}
```

that gives

```
{
  "cid": {
    "type": "uri",
    "value": "http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q236"
  },
  "article_de": {
    "type": "uri",
    "value": "https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montenegro"
  },
  "article_en": {
    "type": "uri",
    "value": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montenegro"
  },
  "country": {
    "xml:lang": "en",
    "type": "literal",
    "value": "Montenegro"
  }
}
```

Try it [here](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fcid%20%3Fcountry%20%3Farticle_en%20%20%3Farticle_de%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fcid%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ3624078%20.%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fcid%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fcountry%20filter%20%28lang%28%3Fcountry%29%20%3D%20%22en%22%29%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fcid%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fcountry%20filter%20%28lang%28%3Fcountry%29%20%3D%20%22de%22%29%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Farticle_en%20schema%3Aabout%20%3Fcid%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Farticle_en%20schema%3AinLanguage%20%22en%22%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28SUBSTR%28str%28%3Farticle_en%29%2C%201%2C%2025%29%20%3D%20%22https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2F%22%29%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Farticle_de%20schema%3Aabout%20%3Fcid%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Farticle_de%20schema%3AinLanguage%20%22de%22%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28SUBSTR%28str%28%3Farticle_de%29%2C%201%2C%2025%29%20%3D%20%22https%3A%2F%2Fde.wikipedia.org%2F%22%29%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%20).

This will require to have a separate property `article_*` for each language.

Putting all together:

```
SELECT ?item ?en ?es ?url_en ?url_es  WHERE { 
{ ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q43229. }
UNION { ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q4830453. }
OPTIONAL { ?item rdfs:label ?en filter (lang(?en) = "en"). }
OPTIONAL { ?item rdfs:label ?es filter (lang(?es) = "es"). }

  OPTIONAL {
      ?url_en schema:about ?item .
      ?url_en schema:inLanguage "en" .
      FILTER (SUBSTR(str(?url_en), 1, 25) = "https://en.wikipedia.org/")
    }
  
  OPTIONAL {
      ?url_es schema:about ?item .
      ?url_es schema:inLanguage "es" .
      FILTER (SUBSTR(str(?url_es), 1, 25) = "https://es.wikipedia.org/")
    }
  
} LIMIT 10
```

Try it [here](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fitem%20%3Fen%20%3Fes%20%3Furl_en%20%3Furl_es%20%20WHERE%20%7B%20%0A%7B%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ43229.%20%7D%0AUNION%20%7B%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ4830453.%20%7D%0AOPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fitem%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fen%20filter%20%28lang%28%3Fen%29%20%3D%20%22en%22%29.%20%7D%0AOPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fitem%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fes%20filter%20%28lang%28%3Fes%29%20%3D%20%22es%22%29.%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Furl_en%20schema%3Aabout%20%3Fitem%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Furl_en%20schema%3AinLanguage%20%22en%22%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28SUBSTR%28str%28%3Furl_en%29%2C%201%2C%2025%29%20%3D%20%22https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2F%22%29%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Furl_es%20schema%3Aabout%20%3Fitem%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Furl_es%20schema%3AinLanguage%20%22es%22%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28SUBSTR%28str%28%3Furl_es%29%2C%201%2C%2025%29%20%3D%20%22https%3A%2F%2Fes.wikipedia.org%2F%22%29%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%7D%20LIMIT%2010).

that gives

```
{
  "item": {
    "type": "uri",
    "value": "http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q130178"
  },
  "en": {
    "xml:lang": "en",
    "type": "literal",
    "value": "Arcadie"
  },
  "es": {
    "xml:lang": "es",
    "type": "literal",
    "value": "Arcadie"
  },
  "url_en": {
    "type": "uri",
    "value": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arcadie"
  },
  "url_es": {
    "type": "uri",
    "value": "https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arcadie_(grupo)"
  }
}
```

Is there a way to group the `url` and the `label` property result like

```
{
    "en": {
        "url": {
            "xml:lang": "es",
            "type": "literal",
            "value": "Arcadie"
        },
        "label": {
            "type": "uri",
            "value": "https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arcadie_(grupo)"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that's not possible with the SPARQL query itself - the SPARQL JSON response format is standardized as is: https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-results-json/

Comment: you would need something like JSON framing, for JSON-LD format (the result would be a graph here, e.g. via CONSTRUCT query) some APIs allow for providing such frames, but I haven't seen such an option for standard SELECT queries to modify the standard SPARQL JSON result format - I guess doing it on client side would be the way to go then

Comment: but maybe JSON-LD and its framing would be interesting for you nevertheless, so here is the reference to it: https://json-ld.org/spec/latest/json-ld-framing/ - and JSON-LD is closer to a domain focused JSON object anyways in my opinion, but it needs a `CONSTRUCT` query then

Comment: @UninformedUser thank you for these details. I did something different when collecting entity properties like in this SELECT query here https://gist.github.com/loretoparisi/e2ccf211c4a723e83944b8a8819146e3